# SQL Server Management Studio access denied

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm getting an error, says "Could not load the DLL xpstar.dll... Reason: 5(Access is denied)" right after logging into SQL Server Management Studio . Even though I can browse through the database schemas but I can't perform any action.

[image: SSMS Error]

`My current configuration:

- SQL Server Enterprise 2016
- SQL Server 2016 Management Studio
- Authentication mode: mixed mode`

[SQL Server services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13jUw.png)

[Binn folder permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTN0u.png)

What I've tried to figure out the cause:

- Check Sql server services and they are all running.
- Try connecting and performing some actions with SQLCMD (list tables, list db schemas...). It's all good.
- Run SSMS as administrator.
- Check permissions of BINN folder.
- Disable Kaspersky Endpoint Security.

None of above steps can resolve the issue. So please kindly help me to fix it.

Comment: I would just install a newer, more modern, and fully supported version of SSMS (e.g. [18.12.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms)) and kiss the 2016 version goodbye. It might not resolve the issue - perhaps Kaspersky or something else has been a little too aggressive locking down the BINN folder, as someone else mentioned and then removed their comment, check and make sure _the SQL Server service account_ has the right permissions and that something hasn't stomped all over SQL Server's ability to function.

Comment: I second @RhythmWasaLurker's comment about the SQL Server service account. That's probably the Windows user actually trying to access the .dll file.

Comment: @RhythmWasaLurker I used version 17.59 earlier but it didn't work. Regarding Kaspersky, I've disabled it yet again, the error still popup. For the checking SQL Server service account part, could you please show me what should I check?

Comment: Having Kaspersky disabled _now_ won't undo any trampling it did over the permissions on your files and folders. Check what service account SQL Server is running as in SQL Server Configuration Manager - right-click the service name in the right-hand side for "SQL Server Services," click properties, and check what account is listed under "Log on as." Then right-click the BINN folder in File Explorer, choose Properties, and on the Security tab, click Edit, and make sure that account is there and has all boxes checked except Full Control.

Comment: Then of course consider whether you want to use Kaspersky at all and, if so, if it has any settings anywhere to leave SQL Server alone.

Comment: @slasky Yes, It's local system account

Comment: @RhythmWasaLurker I'm using local system account. please kindly take a look at the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/13jUw.png

Comment: @RhythmWasaLurker: and this is Binn folder permissions: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTN0u.png

Comment: You can change SQL Server to run as a dedicated service account (just create a new local user, like `MachineName\SQLServerServiceAccount`), then grant that service account all the permissions as mentioned above. This will let you be very granular about permitting only and exactly the things SQL Server needs, add exceptions to "protection" software, and not worry about anything else it might affect regarding the LocalSystem account.

Comment: @RhythmWasaLurker I've just upgraded SSMS to v18.12. i don't get the error popup right after logging in like before. But it's kinda weird. I can use query to select data as well as creating new table. But other than that, it will end up "access denied" error. I've already done like your suggestion that make a new account, add it to administrator group, change sql service to use new account. Also, add that new account to BINN folder access permission. No help.

Comment: I'd open a case with Microsoft support and/or Kaspersky and/or your IT help desk.

Comment: @RhythmWasaLurker Thank you so much for your help. I finally somehow make it work by changing ownership of MSSQL folder from SYSTEM to Administrator account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the folder ownership is the root cause. MSSQL and its subfolders were owned by SYSTEM. Even though Administrators group were assigned full control but They couldn't access to the folder. Probably, Kaspersky is involved. I'm not sure about that.

Solutions:

- Change ownership of folder MSSQL (Drive:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQLXX.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL) from SYSTEM to Administrator.
- Run SSMS as Administrator and problem is solved.